# Asignar fecha y hora actual a elemento del DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

estoy intentando realizar un slider horizontal en el cual, tengo una etiqueta ´p´ a la cual le quiero asignar la hora y fecha actual, pero si lo hago en el ready de jquery, que es cuando ya esta cargada nuestra pagina o documento, solo se mostraria la fecha de ese momento, mas no se seguiria actualizando, espero me de ah entender, dejo el codigo que tengo.

> MI HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/protexa.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Grupo Protexa</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slides" id="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slides" id="slide2"></div>
    <div class="slides" id="slide3"></div>
    <div class="hora"><p class="h1">Aqui vamos a poner la hora</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/protexa.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> MI CSS

```css
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 background: #000000
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.hora{
 position:relative;
 top:10px;
}

.slides {
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 width: 100%;
}

#slide1{
 background: transparent url("http://www.protexa.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Edificio_Mty.jpg") no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 animation: left1 15s infinite;
}

#slide2 {
 background: transparent url("http://www.protexa.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Sol.jpg") no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 animation: left2 15s infinite;
 left: 100%;
}
#slide3 {
 background: transparent url("http://www.protexa.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/protexa.jpg") no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 animation: left3 15s infinite;
 left: 200%;
}

@keyframes left1 {
0% {left: 0%; right:0%;}
26.8% {left: 0%; right:0%;}
33.5% {left: -100%; right: 100%;}
93.8% {left: -200%; right: 200%;}
100% {left: 0%; right: 0%;}
}

@keyframes left2 {
0% {left: 100%; right:-100%;}
26.8% {left: 100%; right:-100%;}
33.5% {left: 0%; right: 0%;}
60.3% {left: 0%; right: 0%;}
67% {left: -100%; right: 100%;}
93.8% {left: -100%; right: 100%;}
100% {left: 100%; right: -100%;}
}

@keyframes left3 {
0% {left: 200%; right:-200%;}
26.8% {left: 200%; right:-200%;}
33.5% {left: 100%; right: -100%;}
60.3% {left: 100%; right: -100%;}
67% {left: 0%; right: 0%;}
93.8% {left: 0%; right: 0%;}
100% {left: 200%; right: -200%;}
}
```

Y aquí es donde planeo poner el codigo javascript para asignarle la hora actual al elemento del DOM.

> ARCHIVO JS

```js
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var fecha = new Date();
//alert("Día: "+fecha.getDate()+"\nMes: "+(fecha.getMonth()+1)+"\nAño: "+fecha.getFullYear());
//alert("Hora: "+fecha.getHours()+"\nMinuto: "+fecha.getMinutes()+"\nSegundo: "+fecha.getSeconds()+"\nMilisegundo: "+fecha.getMilliseconds());
});
```

Comment: si lo que buscas es se actualice de manera constante deberías por ejemplo usando javascript puro usar el método setInterval y colocarle un tiempo de latencia de 1 segundo tal vez para que se obtenga un registro actualizado de la hora

Comment: Como dice @ShadowPaz. Usando JavaScript, usa un setInterval cada un segundo q convierta la hora actual mas un segundo, y q se actualice en el html.

Comment: ¡Gracias, me funciono a la perfección!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imaginate que en este elemento es donde quieres mostrar tu data.

```
<h2 id="reloj"></h2>
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer es en JavaScript utilizar setInterval.

```
var reloj = document.getElementById('reloj');
setInterval(function(){
    var data = new Date();
    reloj.innerHTML = data.getDate()+ "/" + "/" +data.getMonth()+1 + "/"+data.getFullYear()+"/ hora: "+data.toLocaleTimeString();
},1000);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y si quisiera que me desplegara tambien el nombre del dia? por ejemplo "Miércoles" que es el dia de hoy

Comment: Ya lo realicé, gracias por tu ayuda, que tengas un excelente dia!